# How to highlight python indentation in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm new to Python, and just start using PyDev in Eclipse.
Is there a way to highlight the range of my indentation? i.e., show the level of current indent. Like for Java, when click at the beginning of a curly brace ({}), the Eclipse will highlight (bold) the end curly brace. I wonder if there're similar functions for Python.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently implemented in PyDev (although it's already in the TODO list).

Still, you may want to check the EditBox plugin, which may be useful for indentation guides.